# Setting Azure VMSS instance count to 0 until changed manually

Tags: azure, autoscaling, azure-autoscaling-block

I would like to set VMSS instances count to 0 daily at 00:00 UTC. If the VMSS needs to be used the next day, we can scale it again to a desired number manually, and it remains that number of instances for the day til 00:00, and then the autoscale rule should get triggered again at 00:00 and set the instance count to 0. I tried below settings, but it only sets it to 0 for 23:59 to 01:00. And sets it back to 1 instance after 01:00.

If I do not specify the end time, it deletes all instances as soon as I add it.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following config works!

Instead of setting 'Scale to a specific instance count', use 'scale based on a metric', and set threshold which will never be reached wth min 0, max/default to desirable numbers.

[image]